# Weed identification in chicago

Tags: weed-control, weeds

Trying to identify this weed, looks like it might be family of nightshade but not sure. Located in Chicago with Tall Fescue. Any thoughts? Thank you :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could be dandelion that has been hit with weed killer.

Comment: Thank you very much :).